# unable to pass array of strings to identitySource on serverless aws framework on typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

getting below error when I tried to assign array of strings to `identitySource` for HTTP lambda authorizer as below using serverless(typescript)

```
 Type '{ type: string; name: string; identitySource: string[]; resultTtlInSeconds: number; authorizerPayloadFormatVersion: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ arn?: AwsArn; authorizerId?: AwsCfInstruction; claims?: string[]; identitySource?: string; identityValidationExpression?: string; managedExternally?: boolean; name?: string; resultTtlInSeconds?: number; scopes?: string[]; type?: string; }'.
                        Types of property 'identitySource' are incompatible.
                          Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Is there any why we can use multiple `identitySources`

**Note**: yes I have used  authorizerPayloadFormatVersion as '2.0'

```
authorizer: {
          type: 'REQUEST',
          name: 'authorizer',
          identitySource: [
            'method.request.header.Authorization',
            'method.request.header.other-key',
          ],
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a string that contains all the values separated by commas. So in your case, try

```js
authorizer: {
          type: 'REQUEST',
          name: 'authorizer',
          identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization,method.request.header.other-key',
        },
```